# Remove directory from URL while preserving the redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a redirect in place. If a request comes in to the root and the content is available in /website3 it pulls the content in from website3 but only displays the root request. This works really well. For example is a request comes in for example.com/foo/test/ and there is an index.htm file in /website3/foo/test the content displays without including website3 in the url. It also plays nicely if a different path exists like example.com/test it will go to the test directory. This is all perfect.

I am trying to factor out if the request comes in for example.com/website3/foo/test I would like this to redirect to example.com/foo/test but still pull in the content from website3. I have tried a few things and they all result in a loop.

Here is the current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Remove trailing slash on any URL that is requested directly (excludes rewritten URLs)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite root
RewriteRule ^$ website3/ [L]

# If request maps to a directory in "/website3" then rewrite and append trailing slash

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website3/$1 -d 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ website3/$1/ [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website3/$1 -f 
RewriteRule (.*) website3/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive to remove `/website3/` from the start of any URL that is requested directly.

```
# Remove "/website3/" from any URL requested directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^website3/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that this checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var in order to prevent a redirect loop - the same principle as your rule to remove the trailing slash.

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not set (ie. is empty) on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP status) after the first successful rewrite.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.